# KOMA-Script: Adjust text region based on header height

Tags: header-footer, margins, koma-script

I'd like to put an image into the headline using `scrpage2`, but the text runs through the image, because the height of the headline seems not to be adjusted. The `KOMA-Script` documentation doesn't seem to mention anything related to the height of the headline, so I would have thought that this is adjusted automatically.

Is there anything that I can add to the example to have the text start below the image in the headline?

This is the current example, replacing the image with a simple bar for simplicity:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{scrpage2}
\chead{\rule{2cm}{2cm}}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy 
nibh euismod   tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut 
wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit 
lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
\end{document}
```

And that's what it looks like:

[image: example result]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `headheight` class option (here: `headheight=2cm`). You may also want to specify the `headinclude` option so that the header is considered part of the text body for the calculation of margins. See section 2.6 of the `KOMA-Script` manual for details.

```
\documentclass[headheight=2cm,headinclude]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{scrpage2}
\chead{\rule{2cm}{2cm}}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\setheadsepline{0.4pt}% just for the example

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy 
nibh euismod   tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut 
wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit 
lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for mentioning `headinclude`. I spent some time wondering why `headheight` was not working, and couldn't find anything else. It could be better documented in the manual.